# How to tell whether Paypal Web Payments Pro is activated for my account?

Tags: paypal

I've worked with WPP for about 5 years now, and it's really ridiculous how difficult it is to get some simple information. *I know how to sign up for WPP: that's not what this question is about.*

The question is, **for an existing LIVE paypal merchant account, how do I tell definitively and quickly whether WPP has been activated?** I can tell via API when I get the error code 10501 in response, but that is unacceptably late and cumbersome.

My clients can't navigate the byzantine paypal dot com, and I don't know what to tell them. It's making me look like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can ensure that the billing is live is to do the following:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click Profile.
3. Click Manage Monthly Billing under "Billing" on the right side of the page.

You can cancel and reactivate your billing here as well (as long as PayPal did not deactivate your billing).

Here is where to find Manage Monthly Billing It also says if the products are live here, but you cannot edit the billing from this page. The Manage Monthly Billing Page allows you to cancel the billing or reactivate it.

Here's the Profile View for Website Payments Pro (not a Payflow Account):

[image: Profile Example]

If your billing is active it will look like this:

[image: WPP Billing Example]

If you have a PayPal Payments Pro Payflow Edition account, you can log into PayPal Manager at https://manager.paypal.com

The home page of PayPal Manager once logged in shows the status of the account. This particular one is in test status. Here is the profile view

[image: Payflow Information]

If you have a 1.5 edition of PayPal Pro this is an older setup.

1. Click on Profile
2. Click on My Money
3. Click Update next to My Pre Approved Payments
4. Click PayPal Monthly Billing.

If you have a PayPal Billing Agreement and it is Active it will be listed in My Preaproved Payments and also under More Financial Settings . If it is active then your Payments Pro 1.5 is active. If you do not see the billing agreement anywhere then you do not have an active PayPal Pro 1.5 Billing Agreement.

[image: Profile 1.5]

Comment: I don't have any options under profile with the words "manage" or "monthly" or "billing"

Comment: If you have a website payments pro account, when you click profile you should see on the right hand side manager monthly billing. I will get a screen shot for you.

Comment: I checked on an account I know has WPP enabled, Classic edition, NOT Payflow edition. My profile screen looks nothing like the above screenshots.

Comment: That means it must be the 1.5 edition. I will get screen shots for that one for you.

Comment: Update the solution for newer version of PayPal

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke on the phone with PayPal sales and here is what they told me. There is no way when you log into a general PayPal account to see if the organization has PayPal Payments Pro activated. The only way to find this out is to ask the organization if they have a "PayPal Manager" (https://manager.paypal.com) account. If they don't, then the organization doesn't have PayPal Payments Pro setup.

Once they apply for PayPal Payments Pro it usually takes about 5 - 6 days for the process to finalize and their account to be setup. They also told me that if you apply online please don't use Google Chrome, instead use Internet Explorer or Firefox.